# SQL - Naming conditions for filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote MySQL query to filter and count items in a table by date and now a need to get results like:

```
+-----+--------------------+
| cnt | creation_date_date |
+-----+--------------------+
| 90  | 2019-11-15         |
| 31  | 2019-11-16         |
| 9   | 2019-11-17         |
| 80  | 2019-11-18         |
| 40  | 2019-11-19         |
| 32  | 2019-11-20         |
| 132 | 2019-11-21         |
+-----+--------------------+
```

and i got:

```
+-----+
| cnt |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
+-----+
```

I don't know where to declare name `creation_date_date` in mine condition?

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM wallet
WHERE created >= CAST('2019-11-15' AS DATE) 
AND created <= CAST('2019-12-06' AS DATE)
GROUP BY created
```

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: can you add example of `wallet` table?

Comment: Please try below query for desired output , please let me know.

Comment: Commented on your post! Thanks. @AjeetVerma

Comment: Note that `CAST('2019-12-06' AS DATE)` doesn't do anything useful. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output we can only guess. You forgot to display the `created` column with the counts, so we cannot tell what the count refers to. Maybe your `created` column is a datetime and you only want the date?

```
SELECT date(created) as date_created, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM wallet
WHERE created >= date '2019-11-15' AND created < date '2019-12-07'
GROUP BY date(created)
ORDER BY date(created);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please run below query for the desired output ..

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    ,created AS creation_Date_Date
FROM wallet
WHERE created>= CAST('2019-11-15' AS DATE)
    AND created<= CAST('2019-12-06' AS DATE)
GROUP BY created
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. Error log: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR, created, 23) AS creation_date_date
FROM wallet
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,' at line 2 */ @AjeetVerma

Comment: The output is the same with additional field of creation_date_Date. I need to group count all rows added on each day in the range like in the first output in my post.  In first example I did it with count(*) as cnt,
date(created) as creation_date_date . I just need range modification. @AjeetVerma